# Django sign up using OTP send to telegram

Tags: django

Iam using Django User model with extra phone number phone

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']
```

and after, user add all the input need and press sign up button from template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block content %}
    <div style=" position:absolute;
                 top:62%;
                 left:50%;
                 padding:10px;
                 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}{{form|crispy}}
            <p>Have an account? Login <a href="/login">Here</a>!</p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and then i want to change user to verify code page that generate code and send that code to user through telegram.

But because telegram need chat id so the bot can send message to user, i can't figure out how to get that id when user press get code in verify_code template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
{% block content %}
    <div style=" position:absolute;
                 top:50%;
                 left:50%;
                 padding:10px;
                 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">
        <h1>Verify Code</h1>
        <a href="https://t.me/AccountToken_bot" target="_blank">
            Get Code
        </a>
        <p>Enter the 6-digit code you received on Telegram:</p>

        <form method="post" action="{% url 'verify_code' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ user_id }}">
            <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="6">
            <button type="submit">Verify</button>
        </form>
        {{error}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My logic sign up user so far:

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'registration/verify_code.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/sign_up.html', {"form": form})

def verify_code(request):
    code = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)])
    token = '<token>'
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        entered_code = request.POST.get('code')
        # Get the user and the code generated during sign-up
        if code == entered_code:
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/verify_code.html', {'error': 'Invalid code'})

def send_telegram(token, code):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates'
    # code = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)])
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if 'result' in data and data['result']:
            chat_id = data['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id']
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'Your verification code is: {code}')
```

How can i